# Java Security Testing

Tags: java, security, unit-testing, owasp

Is there such a thing as *automated security testing* in Java? If so, how is it implemented? Is it just JUnit tests written to try and exploit known server vulnerabilities, or are their security-centric testing frameworks?

As a segue I'm also interested in this OWASP Security Testing Framework, but can't tell if they're using "framework" in a classic sense (meaning a set of guidelines and procedures to follow), or in a software context (where they are actually providing automated security testing components).

Thanks to any that can shed some light on this for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know is it exactly what you are looking for, but there is a blog post by Stephen Colebourne (author of joda-time and future new standard java8 date-time API) about testing security permissions with junit: [Stephen Colebourne's blog: Testing a security permission](http://blog.joda.org/2004/11/testing-security-permission_5894.html)

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks and I'll check that article out. In the meantime, what I'm looking for is the answer to this: does one use JUnit to write security tests, or is there another framework that (specifically) targets security issues? If so, is OWASP one of them?

Answer (score 3):

Fuzz testing never hurts: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-fuzztest/index.html

Fuzz testing helps you make sure that your application is secure against any opportunity for user input.

Fuzz testing is a little awkward for JUnit tests in a way, because they are "random". You might want to loop and run a number of fuzz tests on each input avenue in a test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) can also be an automated way to find at least some security issues (FindBugs is at quite effective at finding risks of SQL injection and such).

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial tools such as VeraCode that do security scanning.  I don't work for them but my company uses it.  It seems quite thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Automated security testing is *hard* but that doesn't mean its not worth doing.

My suggestion for web apps - use your existing Unit and Integration tests (like Selenium) and then proxy them through a security tool like OWASP ZAP (Zed Attack Proxy).
See http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/SecRegTests for more details.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Yes, Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) is good tool for penetration test

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your Java app actually is. If you are building a web service/API, for example, OWASP have a separate Top 10 just for API's which have things listed in a different priority than the regular top 10. See [OWASP Project API Security](https://owasp.org/www-project-api-security/)

According to Nordic API's, you might find that it involves a lot of manual testing since you can't automate much of, good explanation of the API top 10 here: https://nordicapis.com/testing-owasps-top-10-api-security-vulnerabilities/